# Alternative to GFLAG.exe or registry setting

Tags: windows, crash-reports, crash-dumps, registrykey, gflags

To get the crash-dump i used the below registry setting for windows 7 machine also tried gflags.exe.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps]
"DumpFolder"=hex(2):[path goes here in hex value]
"DumpType"=dword:00000002
"DumpCount"=dword:0000000a
```

This is works well in most of the cases and I am able to get the crash dump when my software crashes. But in one of the cases when I use my software in integration with one more custom software2 I am not able to get crashdump.
I did multiple testing and confirmed that whenever the custom software2 is running along with the main software the crash dumps are not getting generated. The registry setting are not helping. And we need to have custom software2 running along with the main software.

Are there any alternative way (other than registry setting or GFLAGS.exe) or software to generate the crash dumps in this scenario?

I cant debug it because the issue is at the deployed machine.

Comment: *software2* is probably doing its own exception handling, either in a try/catch block or with an unhandled exception handler or both. That setting is an operating system (kernel) setting. If it does not work, you're out of luck. Ask the vendor to turn it off, ask if there is a config file to bypass that behavior or a command line switch or any other way to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

since none of the utilities are helping i am using the task manager to get the crash-dump. When my application crashes windows displays the window. During that time i am generating the crash-dump using task manager manually.For 32 bit application use the task manger from SYSWOR64 folder.